# Combo box will not display values from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to fill a combo box from a custom table in Wordpress.               `print_r(array_values($cellco_options))` returns the expected array of 15 items.
My `foreach` statement is a problem.  If I echo the variables the combobox will not fill with items.  If I remove the echo the combox fills with 15 items but they are blank.

Questions: 
Why is echo not allowing the box to fill?
How can I fill my box with items I can see, is echo the wrong method in this case?

```
    <?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $cellco_options=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`, `cellco` FROM `ea_cellcarrier` WHERE 1"); 
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="cell_carrier<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Cell Carrier', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>

        <select type="text" name="cell_carrier" id="cell_carrier<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" tabindex="20" />
            <option disabled selected value=""> -- select -- </option>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($cellco_options as $id => $cellco) { ?>
                    <option value= "<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $cellco; ?></option>
                <?php   }
                ?>
        </select>           
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you miken32, I tried your tip and still had the blank spaces, however, your tip led to the following solution that works:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $cellco_options=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`, `cellco` FROM `ea_cellcarrier` WHERE 1"); 
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="cell_carrier<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Cell Carrier', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
        <select type="text" name="cell_carrier" id="cell_carrier<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>" tabindex="20">
            <option selected value="" > -- select -- </option>
                <?php foreach ($cellco_options as $option):?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $option->id; ?>" >
                    <?php echo $option->cellco; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code I posted, but using an object return from `get_results()` instead of an array. You could at least do me the courtesy of an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your [database results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) are not indexed by `id` so your foreach loop was not getting what you expected.

Also note the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) I used with the `foreach()` loop. It can be much easier to read in cases like this where you're mixing your PHP with HTML.

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$cellco_options=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`, `cellco` FROM `ea_cellcarrier`", ARRAY_N); 
?>

<p>
    <label for="cell_carrier<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Cell Carrier', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <select type="text" name="cell_carrier" id="cell_carrier<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" tabindex="20">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=""> -- select -- </option>
<?php foreach ($cellco_options as $option):?>
        <option value= "<?php echo $option[0]?>"><?php echo $option[1]?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </select>           
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select html tag is closed at the end of the line.

And you can use [php alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/ro/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for the code.

```
  <?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $cellco_options=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`, `cellco` FROM `ea_cellcarrier` WHERE 1"); 
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="cell_carrier<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Cell Carrier', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>

        <select type="text" name="cell_carrier" id="cell_carrier<?php echo $template->the_instance(); ?>" tabindex="20">
            <option disabled selected value=""> -- select -- </option>
                <?php foreach ($cellco_options as $id => $cellco): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $cellco; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </p>
```